# Converting spectra to rgb colour

Tags: visible-light, spectroscopy, visualization

I am having trouble obtaining RGB colour values from the spectra of an object.  I have the specific flux $F_\nu$ as a function of $\nu$ for each pixel of the image I'd like to make, but am unsure of how to turn this into RGB.

The proper method seems to be to calculate the $XYZ$ values by integrating the spectral power density $P(\lambda) = \nu^2 F_\nu /c$ against the CIE standard observer functions, then doing a linear transformation into $RGB$ space.  However, I can not seem to find a reference that gives the normalization for the transformation into XYZ.

My question is: am I approaching this in the right way, and if so how is the transformation from spectra to $XYZ$ normalized?  Thanks!

Comment: You can find the conversion matrices for a variety of colorspaces here:  http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

Answer (score 3):

You can find the conversion matrices for a variety of colorspaces here:  http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html and the format for integrating the input spectrum at [RIT](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_spectr.html).   Quoting from the latter:

[image: COnversion process]

So, I'm guessing the part you're missing is the x,y,z curves in the second row there. Go to Wikipedia or some other optics-related site to get as detailed a set of numbers for the  x, y, and z  response curves and the integral (done numerically) is pretty straightforward.